# Spark count parameter "mentions" in the rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is the example DF:

```
Car       Model  Colors
Toyota    RAV4   Red, Black
Toyota    Camry  Red, White
```

(there can be any number of colors listed)

How would I change the initial DF to this (without 
    duplicating every row and counting by matches on first 2 columns)?

```
Toyota    Black   1
Toyota    Red     2
Toyota    White   1
```

(where numbers mean how many models of !each! car manufacturer are available in a certain color)

**P.S** Here is my take on the question:

```
val folded = rdd
  .groupBy(_.manufacturer)
  .mapValues(_.foldLeft(mutable.HashMap.empty[String, Long])((hm, el) => el.colors.foreach(color => hm(color) = hm(color) + 1)))
```

which gives me the counts. Though I am not sure how to generate a DF needed out of '**folded**'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to split colors column then explode it, and finally group by color and car,
try the following code;

```
scala> val initialDf = spark.createDataFrame(List(("Toyota","RAV4","Red,Black"),("Toyota","Camry","Red,White"))).toDF("Car","Model","Colors")

scala> initialDf.select($"Car",explode(split($"Colors",",")).as("Color")).groupBy($"Car",$"Color").agg(count($"Color").as("cnt")).show()

+------+-----+---+
|   Car|Color|cnt|
+------+-----+---+
|Toyota|White|  1|
|Toyota|  Red|  2|
|Toyota|Black|  1|
+------+-----+---+
```